# How to get distance from latitude and longitude from mysql Address table which have latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 $distance = DB::select(
                DB::raw("
                SELECT a.distance
                FROM ( SELECT user_id, street, store_name,
                    (
                        '".$mean_radius_of_Earth."' * 
                        acos(cos(radians('".$latitude."')) * 
                        cos(radians(latitude)) * 
                        cos(radians(longitude) - 
                        radians('".$longitude."')) + 
                        sin(radians('".$latitude."')) * 
                        sin(radians(latitude)))
                    ) AS distance
                    FROM addresses ) AS a
                    WHERE id= '". $address_id."' 

                ")
            );
```

I have to get all the column of the particular row using this address_id which is the primary key but i am getting the error:- Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'  but when i am trying to achieve that with user_id then i am getting that all fields data ,user_id(which is not primary_key) your help will be much appreciated,
**thanks in Advance** and sorry for the improper english

Comment: what table is the primary key `id` in?

Comment: Rolling your own GIS functions is a bad plan. Why not use the built-in [GIS functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html)?

Comment: This also has huge [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/) because raw data is injected without proper escaping. Can't you use placeholder values?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't select id in your subrequest so or you make the select in the subquery or you select the field id in your subselect:

```
$distance = DB::select(
            DB::raw("
            SELECT a.distance
            FROM ( SELECT user_id, street, store_name,
                (
                    '".$mean_radius_of_Earth."' * 
                    acos(cos(radians('".$latitude."')) * 
                    cos(radians(latitude)) * 
                    cos(radians(longitude) - 
                    radians('".$longitude."')) + 
                    sin(radians('".$latitude."')) * 
                    sin(radians(latitude)))
                ) AS distance
                FROM addresses 
                WHERE id= '". $address_id."') AS a                    

            ")
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

In situation like this I would leverage the power of [Eloquent's Appends](http://laraveldaily.com/why-use-appends-with-accessors-in-eloquent/) functionality.

In your situation it might look a little like the following,

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['distance'];

    /**
     * Get the distance for the user.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDistanceAttribute()
    {
        $distance = // Crazy math for distance insert here

        // To get address long and lat stored in separate database 
        // I would eager load them in the query call and then in this 
        // function you'd already have the values ready to go in memory
        $distance = $this->address->long...

        return $distance;
    }
}
```

The beauty of this solution is you can leverage Eloquent's querying, prevent SQL injection messes, and keep things tied to your Model not the query.

```
use App\User;

foreach(User::all() as $user) {
    echo $user->distance; // Print's out the distance you wanted
}

echo User::where('id', '=', $address_id)->first()->distance; // Prints out specific user's distance.
```